# Coordinates in decimal degrees in QGIS

Tags: coordinates

My project is set as WGS84, my layer too.

I have re-projected it. I have copied my layer. I have used "Add Geometry attributes," choosing the right CRS, but I'm still having my coordinates in meters!

Any new ideas?

Layer information

Información del proveedor

Almacenamiento
ESRI Shapefile
Comentario

Codificación
UTF-8
Geometría
Point (Point)
SRC
EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geográfico
Extensión
369138.2846000003628433,6129075.0881999991834164 : 849050.3508999999612570,6663955.9552999995648861
Unidad
grados
Número de objetos
2.901

Comment: Please describe more detailed what you have done: how did you reproject it

Comment: What kind of data are you using the tool on?  Points, lines, or polygons?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text from Layer Properties > Information

Comment: include text from  Layer Properties->Source->Data Source or DataFrame Properties->Coordinate System->Current Coordinate System might help

Comment: 1- I use reproject gGis tool, reprojecting to WGS 84,    2- its a poing layer